# No Gmail application option in Google workspace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail, google-workspace

Recently I defined Google Cloud organization - `myorganization.com` with admin `myuser@.myorganization.com`. When I try to achieve Gmail for this user I receive a message:

> We are sorry, but you do not have access to Gmail. Please log in to your Admin Console to enable Gmail.

The problem is that in my Admin Console in Google Workspace Gmail is not listed as an application.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Google supplies business email only to business types of subscription. I was on the free tier and so the email option was not available.

Comment: Thanks! It would be nice if [their documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/57919?hl=en) mentioned that in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin console `admin.google.com` and login with your credentials.

If you have the admin privileges then you will be able enable gmail for your account:

> - From the Admin console Home page, go to Apps and then Google > Workspacea nd then Gmail.
> - Click Service status.
> - To turn on or off a service for everyone in your organization, click On for everyone or Off for everyone, and then click Save.

Have a look at documentation which explains [how to enable / disable gmail for workspace users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/57919?hl=en).

Comment: It doesn't exist for any users who don't subscribe to any premium plan. It seems we must pay a business subscription for that.

Answer (score 0):

Using a free tier, once you signup to Google Workspace, you must also attribute the Google Workspace licence to the admin user using `https://admin.google.com/ac/billing/licensesettings`

Then the Workspace Account will have the related services activated.